# Javascript issue with IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

My app was working fine till IE9, now it stopped working when I upgraded it to IE11. Here is a sample html and js .

### ISSUE

In the first run ie. **on load** it works well. But when I ***select*** PDA brand, second dropdown's all options went blank.

In console there was a script error `Invalid Calling Object error` on object `clonedOptions`.

```js
function dynamicSelect(id1, id2) {
  //alert("Everytime")
  // Browser and feature tests to see if there is enough W3C DOM support

  // Obtain references to both select boxes
  var sel1 = document.getElementById(id1);
  var sel2 = document.getElementById(id2);
  // Clone the dynamic select box
  var clone = sel2.cloneNode(true);
  // Obtain references to all cloned options
  var clonedOptions = clone.getElementsByTagName("option");
  // Onload init: call a generic function to display the related options in the dynamic select box
  refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions);
  // Onchange of the main select box: call a generic function to display the related options in the dynamic select box

  sel1.onchange = function() {
    refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions);
  };
}

function refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions) {
  while (sel2.options.length) {
    sel2.remove(0);
  }

  //alert(sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value)

  // Create regular expression objects for "select" and the value of the selected option of the main select box as class names
  var pattern1 = /( |^)(select)( |$)/;
  var pattern2 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value + ")( |$)");
  // Iterate through all cloned options
  //alert(clonedOptions.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions.length; i++) {
    // If the classname of a cloned option either equals "select" or equals the value of the selected option of the main select box

    if (clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern1) || clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern2)) {
      // Clone the option from the hidden option pool and append it to the dynamic select box
      //alert("Did match")

      sel2.appendChild(clonedOptions[i].cloneNode(true));
      //alert(sel2.options[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
  <title>dynamic selectbox example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="unobtrusivedynamicselect_ex5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <div>
      <select id="pda-brand">
        <option value="select">Select PDA brand...</option>
        <option value="dell">Dell</option>
        <option value="hp">HP</option>
        <option value="palmone">PalmOne</option>
      </select>
      <select id="pda-type">
        <option class="select" value="select">Select PDA type...</option>
        <option class="dell" value="aximx30">Axim X30</option>
        <option class="dell" value="aximx50">Axim X50</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqhx2750">iPAQ hx2750</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqrx3715">iPAQ rx3715</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqrz1710">iPAQ rz1710</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="tungstene2">Tungsten E2</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="tungstent5">Tungsten T5</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="zire72">Zire 72</option>
      </select>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(e) {
          dynamicSelect("pda-brand", "pda-type");
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

### LINE OF ISSUE

in below loc, for clonedOptions i am getting  Invalid Calling Object error.

```
for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions.length; i++) {
```

Comment: I guess it happens because some `options` in `clonedOptions` do not exists anymore and you use the original version of `clonedOptions` every times

Comment: @Hacketo, its working in all browsers except IE11

Comment: yes, I read the code and it's supposed to work, but we're talking about IE ^^, what is the line that throw the error ?

Comment: @Hacketo, see my updated question

Comment: @Hacketo in the IE changelist guide, i came across somewhere in google that said IE 11 is no more support global variables.

Comment: I tried something and it seem work, I keep one reference of an option in a variable, could you check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Hacketo/dy9e9de5/ having some trouble to test ie11

Comment: @AmitRanjan mmmm, that sounds very unlikely, reference link? You probably mean that IE edge doesn't create globals out of IDs? http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/1c1h4gf3/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get this working in IE-11, Please try by yourself.

As per my understanding the issue is:

```
var clone = sel2.cloneNode(true);
var clonedOptions = clone.getElementsByTagName("option");
```

`clonedOptions` is probably a reference to children of `clone` with tag name `option`

```
  sel1.onchange = function() {
    refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions);
  };
```

In this function there is a reference to `clonedOptions`, but no reference to `clone`. So `clone` is probably garbageCollected as IE couldn't find any reason to keep it. `clonedOptions` keeps a reference to a collection that doesn't exist.

You could correct in your own way, I am just passing `clone` instead of `clonedOptions` and it works for me in `IE11`

```js
function dynamicSelect(id1, id2) {
  //alert("Everytime")
  // Browser and feature tests to see if there is enough W3C DOM support

  // Obtain references to both select boxes
  var sel1 = document.getElementById(id1);
  var sel2 = document.getElementById(id2);
  // Clone the dynamic select box      // Obtain references to all cloned options
  var clone = sel2.cloneNode(true);
  // Onload init: call a generic function to display the related options in the dynamic select box
  refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clone);
  // Onchange of the main select box: call a generic function to display the related options in the dynamic select box

  sel1.onchange = function() {
    refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clone);
  };
}

function refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clone) {
  var clonedOptions = clone.getElementsByTagName("option");
  while (sel2.options.length) {
    sel2.remove(0);
  }

  //alert(sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value)

  // Create regular expression objects for "select" and the value of the selected option of the main select box as class names
  var pattern1 = /( |^)(select)( |$)/;
  var pattern2 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value + ")( |$)");
  // Iterate through all cloned options
  //alert(clonedOptions.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions.length; i++) {
    // If the classname of a cloned option either equals "select" or equals the value of the selected option of the main select box

    if (clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern1) || clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern2)) {
      // Clone the option from the hidden option pool and append it to the dynamic select box
      //alert("Did match")

      sel2.appendChild(clonedOptions[i].cloneNode(true));
      //alert(sel2.options[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
  <title>dynamic selectbox example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="unobtrusivedynamicselect_ex5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <div>
      <select id="pda-brand">
        <option value="select">Select PDA brand...</option>
        <option value="dell">Dell</option>
        <option value="hp">HP</option>
        <option value="palmone">PalmOne</option>
      </select>
      <select id="pda-type">
        <option class="select" value="select">Select PDA type...</option>
        <option class="dell" value="aximx30">Axim X30</option>
        <option class="dell" value="aximx50">Axim X50</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqhx2750">iPAQ hx2750</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqrx3715">iPAQ rx3715</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqrz1710">iPAQ rz1710</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="tungstene2">Tungsten E2</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="tungstent5">Tungsten T5</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="zire72">Zire 72</option>
      </select>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(e) {
          dynamicSelect("pda-brand", "pda-type");
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using `getElementsByTagName` which returns a live list, which means that if an item is removed from the DOM, it is also removed from the list and is therefore eligible for garbage collection. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

> The returned list is live, meaning that it updates itself with the DOM tree automatically.

The following example will explain what I mean

```js
var ps = document.body.getElementsByTagName('p');
var ps2 = document.body.querySelectorAll('p');
console.log(ps.length); // 3
document.body.removeChild(ps[0]);
console.log(ps.length);  // 2
console.log(ps2.length);  // 3
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

I don't have the latest IE, but I have a strong feeling that if you use `clone.querySelectorAll("option")`, you won't have the same problem because the nodes will not become eligible for garbage collection since the list it returns is not live.

```js
function dynamicSelect(id1, id2) {
  //alert("Everytime")
  // Browser and feature tests to see if there is enough W3C DOM support

  // Obtain references to both select boxes
  var sel1 = document.getElementById(id1);
  var sel2 = document.getElementById(id2);
  // Clone the dynamic select box
  var clone = sel2.cloneNode(true);
  // Obtain references to all cloned options
  var clonedOptions = clone.querySelectorAll("option");
  // Onload init: call a generic function to display the related options in the dynamic select box
  refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions);
  // Onchange of the main select box: call a generic function to display the related options in the dynamic select box

  sel1.onchange = function() {
    refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions);
  };
}

function refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions) {
  while (sel2.options.length) {
    sel2.remove(0);
  }

  //alert(sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value)

  // Create regular expression objects for "select" and the value of the selected option of the main select box as class names
  var pattern1 = /( |^)(select)( |$)/;
  var pattern2 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value + ")( |$)");
  // Iterate through all cloned options
  //alert(clonedOptions.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions.length; i++) {
    // If the classname of a cloned option either equals "select" or equals the value of the selected option of the main select box

    if (clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern1) || clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern2)) {
      // Clone the option from the hidden option pool and append it to the dynamic select box
      //alert("Did match")

      sel2.appendChild(clonedOptions[i].cloneNode(true));
      //alert(sel2.options[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
  <title>dynamic selectbox example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="unobtrusivedynamicselect_ex5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <div>
      <select id="pda-brand">
        <option value="select">Select PDA brand...</option>
        <option value="dell">Dell</option>
        <option value="hp">HP</option>
        <option value="palmone">PalmOne</option>
      </select>
      <select id="pda-type">
        <option class="select" value="select">Select PDA type...</option>
        <option class="dell" value="aximx30">Axim X30</option>
        <option class="dell" value="aximx50">Axim X50</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqhx2750">iPAQ hx2750</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqrx3715">iPAQ rx3715</option>
        <option class="hp" value="ipaqrz1710">iPAQ rz1710</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="tungstene2">Tungsten E2</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="tungstent5">Tungsten T5</option>
        <option class="palmone" value="zire72">Zire 72</option>
      </select>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(e) {
          dynamicSelect("pda-brand", "pda-type");
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP used `getElementsByTagName ` on a clone, "The duplicate node returned by cloneNode() is not part of the document until it is added to another node that is part of the document" does that mean that `getElementsByTagName` on a clonedNode make no sense ?

Comment: He is not removing items from `clone` anywhere. Any idea why `clone` gets Garbage Collected?

Comment: That's true, it does seem to fix it though... hopefully somebody can take what I started and run with it, I have to get going :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between live lists and normal lists.

Comment: @sabithpocker It may have something to do with the fact that the cloned node never gets attached to the DOM?